# Role "postgres" already exists & Role "postgres" does not exist at the same time

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, microservices, spring-cloud

I'm trying to launch my spring boot microservices project in docker compose file.

Provided User : postgres
Provided Password : password

When I try to connect service with postgres db, console says this:

```
2023-05-07 10:30:48 2023-05-07T07:30:48.725Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-05-07 10:30:49 2023-05-07T07:30:49.863Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
2023-05-07 10:30:49 
2023-05-07 10:30:49 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
...
```

But I'm entirely sure that passed credentials are right.

At the same time, the docker container I'm trying to connect to says that

```
2023-05-07 10:30:51 2023-05-07 07:30:51.287 UTC [41] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
2023-05-07 10:30:51     Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
```

If I try to create user named 'postgres' postgresql console tells me that it already exists;

docker-compose.yml file

```
  postgres-order:
    container_name: postgres-order
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: order_service
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-order:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5431:5431"
    command: -p 5431
    expose:
      - "5431"
    restart: always

  
  order-service:
    container_name: order-service
    image: registry.hub.docker.com/jirafus400/order-service:latest
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-order:5431/order_service
    depends_on:
      - postgres-order
      - broker
      - eureka-server
      - api-gateway
```

application-docker.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-order:5431/order_service
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
server.port=8080
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka:password@eureka-server:8761/eureka
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=broker:29092
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was that the volumes was created with a different postgres credentials. And after I change credentials they're not matched. Just removed volumes and it all worked.